# linux server Creates cache and laravel project gone down

Tags: linux, caching, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I have stuck in a problem that my laravel project deployed in linux server and server is creating cache in var directory. I run `'yum clean all'` command but again creates cache.
I run command `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan route:clear` but no result.
is there any way to manage server cache?
I face, the error is...

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81:
file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 255 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space
```

**my project size is 120 mb.**﻿

Answer (score 0):

The one of the possible reason is, if the page size is greater than 4k. The servers usually cache the pages with larger size. The size increases with the data coming from database or excessive use of java script.

And these cache can not be cleared using laravel commands.